# JavaScript multiple keydown

Tags: javascript, html, onkeydown

First, I would like to thank all for your help and replies.

I'm working on a project that required users to press a key and hold it, it will trigger an action.

When the user presses another key ( still holing the first key), it will trigger another action.

However, I'm stuck getting JavaScript to recognize two keys being pressed at the same time.

```js
var down = false;
var keys;

document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (down) {return;}
    down = true;
    keys = (keys || []);
    keys[e.keyCode]=true;
    if (keys[87]){
        console.log("1");

    }
    else if (keys[83]){
        console.log("2");
    }
    else if (keys[83] && keys[87]){
        console.log("sucessfull");
    }
} , false);

document.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    down = false;
    keys[e.keyCode]=false;
    stop();
}, false);
```

```html
<button id="up" onmousedown="Drive(1)" onmouseup="Drive(2)">UP </button>
```

Comment: When your second keydown event is received, the down boolean will be true and the function will immediately return. 

It looks like if you remove the down variable (and associated checks/returns) your code might achieve what you want it to already.

Answer (score 3):

1. Removed the 'down' variable checks
2. Removed the mouse button element thing - didn't seem relevant to your problem?
3. Removed the extra HTML body
4. Got rid of the else branching as it would be satisfied (by 87 or 83) before ever getting to the && condition

   ```
       var keys;

       document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
           keys = (keys || []);
           keys[e.keyCode]=true;
           if (keys[87]){
               console.log("1");

           }

           if (keys[83]){
               console.log("2");
           }

           if (keys[83] && keys[87]){
               console.log("sucessfull");
           }
       } , false);

       document.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
           keys[e.keyCode]=false;
           stop();
       }, false);
   ```

Comment: The reason why I add boolean there because I don't want HTML to repeat action when holding a key.