# what is wrong between two "multiple key pressed" code sample?

Tags: javascript, html, onkeydown

I was trying to get multiple key pressed at the same time functionality. I found some answer for that. I was following this one.

[JavaScript multiple keydown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53405049/javascript-multiple-keydown)

The problem is I got some of that code which work. But My version of that does not work. I am totally clueless whats going on.

Code from the answer

```
var keys;

document.getElementById('demo').addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    keys = (keys || []);
    keys[e.keyCode]=true;

    if (keys[65] && keys[66]){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
} , false);

document.getElementById('demo').addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    keys[e.keyCode]=false;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    stop();
}, false);
```

My version of code is.

```
var keys;

document.getElementById('demo').addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
keys = (keys || []);
    keys[e.keycode]=true;
    if (keys[65] && keys[66]){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
} , false);
document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    keys[e.keycode]=false;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
//stop();
} , false);
```

In my version of code first part is not working. I can't figure out why?

Comment: `keyCode` vs. `keycode`

Comment: Thanks. That "C" vs "c".

Answer (score 0):

original

```js
 keys[e.keyCode]=true; 
stop();
```

VS.yours

```js
keys[e.keycode]=true;
//stop();
```

Comment: stop() was not the problem. I tried with it too. 'keyCode' spelling was wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. `keycode` needs to be written as `keyCode` in both places.
2. Make sure the demo element is an input, it won't work with div, etc.